# why does not my jQuery date picker UI plugin not show up/down arrows in the year field

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

As per this [problematic example](http://www.ucanwest.ca/admissions/apply/online-application/?form=Application&page=3&ref=291ed3b6-4ef2-4869-bff1-8d21529ed7a3), I can't seem to get the up and down arrows to choose a date earlier than 2001 or later than 2021.

```
Education Record
    did you complete high school? * --> Yes
    clicking Graduation Date *  
        clicking 2013 down arrow
```

[image: example]

any ideas what's causing this? The scroll arrows do not show up at all in IE10 in windows 7 and in Firefox the scroll arrows are shown but it can not be scrolled before 2001 or after 2021. The work around is to choose the min or max date and click the arrow again to show before or after years.

Comment: i have the scroll bars but it seems that is the range of the years. you don't see them because it so happens that on your screen the dropdown can stretch on its entire height to cover all the options

Comment: you can add a `size="5"` attribute on that select that will only show a 5 items tall list and you will have the scrollbars

Comment: @TheBrain: Adding size="5" shows the scroll bar but does nor show dates before 2002 of after 2022

Comment: then you need to change the range of the years to be between fixed years, and not -someting:+someting because it seems that doesn't work too well.

Comment: in my PC i tried it in FF,Chrome,IE.
and in all browser it is working fine.
1995 to 2015 value is coming.

Comment: Could you show the relevant code in your question and in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: I tried looking into your code and, I'm sorry, but it is an absolute mess. Please try to clean it up some and provide the relevant code so we can assist you. You may want to even consider starting from scratch...

Comment: is that ur programming need or user need

Answer (score 9):

Try this- [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/STLRf/1/)

```
$(function () {
 $("#datepicker").datepicker({
     changeMonth: true,
     changeYear: true,
     yearRange: "-120:+10", // magic!
     dateFormat: 'mm/yy',
     onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
         var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
         var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
         $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
     }
  });
});
```

[API Documentation for `yearRange`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-yearRange)

Comment: Yes the default for `yearRange` is -10 to +10 years. This is best answer.

Answer (score 2):

As i see in your screenshot that you're using IE10 which is has a freaky style a bit. Your select dropdown list will work fine in good browsers such as Chrome, FF, Safari, etc...
am pretty sure if you set a fixed height for the select element which is has
.ui-datepicker-year class,  for example height: 150px; and add overflow: auto; hope this helps

Comment: what's the point of showing the arrows if you want to show all the years list?

Answer (score 2):

In jQuery-UI you can easily specify years range and default date.

```
    $( "#specific_birthdate" ).datepicker( {
        yearRange : "1950:2011",
        changeYear : true,
        defaultDate : new Date(1970, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    } );
```